# Magento 2.4.0 Upgrade Reordered Shipping & Billing Address Fields

Tags: magento2.4

After upgrading to Magento 2.4.0 from 2.3.5, the Shipping and Billing Address fields in both the frontend and the backend are reordered. The new order is FName, LName, Company, St Address, County, State, City, Zip, Phone. Is this now the default?

Answer (score 0):

That's how it looks like in my 2.4.0 [image: backend]

Comment: for frontend the order is same as you mentioned i-e `FName, LName, Company, St Address, County, State, City, Zip, Phone`